# How to trigger a Jenkins build when a push is made to a private github repository 

Tags: git, plugins, github, build-process, jenkins

My Jenkins Continuous Integration Server is on running on a Ubuntu host, configured as follows:

- Jenkins v 1.463
- github-api 1.23
- Jenkins GIT plugin 1.1.18
- GitHub plugin 1.2

**Polling SCM works.** This is important to say because I want you to know my other jenkins related configuration is working well except this post build trigger nonsense.

I want to configure Jenkins so that when changes are pushed to a development branch in a **private github repository** this will then trigger a build that incorporates the most recent changes.

The repo is under my personal github account as owner. Let's call this *owner*

I am including another github.com account as collaborator. Let's call this *collaborator*

The reason I am doing this is because in case I am no longer involved in the project, somebody else can carry on with the maintenance.

The SSH keys for the jenkins user in ubuntu are stored under *collaborator*

I have consulted the following links:

http://nepalonrails.tumblr.com/post/14217655627/set-up-jenkins-ci-on-ubuntu-for-painless-rails3-app-ci

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10391

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin

http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging

http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/01/better-integration-between-jenkins-and.html

None of it is not working. Some look a bit dated or even contradictory.

I have added github.com to knownhosts for jenkins ubuntu user.
I have added the github webhook.

I have tried manual and auto github webhook setup in jenkins.

Nothing works.

I need a step by step guide on how to achieve this without polling github.

Comment: I have configured the following logger in my jenkins http://cl.ly/Gy15 Nothing is showing up in the bottom 2 logger

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and after looking at the main Jenkins **System Log** I saw the following:

```
Feb 15, 2013 8:35:44 PM hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter doFilter
WARNING: No valid crumb was included in request for /github-webhook/.  Returning 403.
```

The solution is to switch off the CSRF protection - Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits. The checkbox is just at the bottom of the first configuration section. After that it all seemed to work happily.

Comment: on jenkins on cloudbees.com the Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery Explouts does not appear! Is there another way to disable CSRF. For example using Jenkins CLI?

Comment: The setting moved to `Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security > Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits`, at the very bottom of the page. Using Jenkins version 1.572

Comment: In case it can help anyone, this solution also works for the same error, but with `/bitbucket-hook`

Answer (score 2):

Create a logger with  trace level logging for the `com.cloudbees.jenkins` category under your `/log` url (Manage Jenkins-> System logs).

Verify that there is a **Webhook URL** entry under the **Service Hooks** section of your repository administration screen.

Click **test hook** and you should see some log activity under your newly created logger.

Finally, check the **GitHub Polling** log action on the build which you have configured to be triggered by GitHub pushes.

A common mistake is testing commit hooks like this *without having a change present.*

*The hook is only used to prompt a poll and won't perform a build unless changes are detected.*

Comment: I followed your advice. i added to webhook url. nothing happened during when I pressed Test hook.

I added to jenkins hook url and press Test hook. there is a payload sent on github.com website.

When i check the logger,  nothing happened.

DO I need to switch off the SCM Polling when I run this test?

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots?