# Why won't Jenkins build my project when I push to Github?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Jenkins 2.32.1, all plugins updated to latest versions today. I had this problem with somewhat older versions of plugins so I don't think it's just a recent plugin bug.

My project builds fine when I ask it to in the Jenkins UI. It also builds fine when I configure it to poll. However, I can't get it to build triggered by pushing to Github.

In my project's configuration,

- "Github project" is checked and the URL (https://github.com/myorg/myrepo/) is entered below that
- "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" is checked
- and then there is

[image]

On the Github side, I have

[image]

Webhook deliveries are successful, i.e. return HTTP status 200.

On https://jenkins.myorg.com/job/api/GitHubPollLog/ I see

```
Last GitHub Push
Started on Jan 11, 2017 10:33:41 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision ee4b3fe5b57ecd5ae5875bce573b32bb60074dfa (refs/remotes/origin/master)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git # timeout=10
Found 2 remote heads on git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision ee4b3fe5b57ecd5ae5875bce573b32bb60074dfa (refs/remotes/origin/master)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git # timeout=10
Found 2 remote heads on git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git
Done. Took 2 sec
No changes
```

The "last built revision" lines do indeed say the SHA of the revision that was most recently built (manually). But there are changes, because I just pushed a bogus update for testing purposes.

In Jenkins' main log I see

```
Jan 11, 2017 10:33:41 PM INFO
org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber onEvent
Received POST for https://github.com/myorg/myrepo
Jan 11, 2017 10:33:41 PM INFO
org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.subscriber.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1 run
Poked api
```

and nothing more.

I know similar questions have been asked many times. I've checked all of the considerations mentioned in

- [Jenkins-Build when a change is pushed to GitHub option is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576881/jenkins-build-when-a-change-is-pushed-to-github-option-is-not-working)
- [How to trigger a Jenkins build when a push is made to a private github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633827/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-when-a-push-is-made-to-a-private-github-repositor)

without success and read many others without getting any other insight. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually bypassed this problem by switching to the Jenkins functionality that scans one's Github organization and automatically creates a job for each repo with a Jenkins file. Repos thus created did build automatically when pushed to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using public IP for your Jenkins server?

I run on the same problem, and I am using socketxp for making a tunnel for the hooks to be public but still does not work, so I switch to Poll SCM

[image]

Comment: It's been a few years and I no longer recall the details of that setup, but I'm pretty sure it was a public IP.

Answer (score -1):

We are using Jenkins ver 1.570-CIaaS, This have the below option which make the build trigger for every PR ( PR from any user ).

Build Triggers This have an option GitHub Pull Request Builder .

Not sure whether i answer to your question , just in case if this information helps.